# how to resolve the error: Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded(limit 32)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am creating a view using another view inner join(ed) with a table valued function ,
this table valued function calls a Scalar valued function to populate one of its column,  when I execute the same,
i get  error stating : `Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded(limit 32)`

can anyone help .....plz

*Below is the table valued function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[sstfnAllSubjectWithAASDID] 
 (
 )
RETURNS 
@tt TABLE 
(
     AASDID numeric(18,0),
 SubjectString nvarchar(MAX),
 SubjectCount int
)
    AS
        BEGIN
        declare @pID numeric(18,0)
        declare @pStr nvarchar(MAx)
        declare @pCount int
        Declare LAASDID Cursor Read_Only Fast_Forward for (SELECT AASDid  from          vwAcdAdmissionSessionDetailWithAcdAdmissionSessionSubjectDetail)
                                            open LAASDID

                                            FETCH next from LAASDID into @pID
                                                while(@@FETCH_STATUS =0) 
                                            BEGIN
                                            set @pCount = (SELECT   COUNT( MasterSubject.SubjectName ) as cnt
                                                            FROM         AcdAdmissionSessionSubjectDetail INNER JOIN
                                                                MasterSubject ON AcdAdmissionSessionSubjectDetail.SubjectId = MasterSubject.SubjectId where
                                                                AcdAdmissionSessionSubjectDetail.AASDID = @pID

                                                                )
                                            set @pStr = (SELECT [dbo].[ssspfnGetSubjectname] (@pID))
                                            Insert Into  @tt (AASDID,SubjectString,SubjectCount) values (@pID,@pStr,@pCount)
                                            FETCH next from LAASDID into @pID
                                            END



RETURN 

END
```

- And this is the scalar valued function which it calls

  ```
   ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ssspfnGetSubjectname]
         (
          @pAASDID numeric(18,0)
         )
         RETURNS nvarchar(max)
         AS
         BEGIN

  DECLARE @Cols1 as nvarchar(max)

   set @Cols1 = STUFF(  (SELECT DISTINCT SubjectName + ','
                          FROM      (     SELECT     AcdAdmissionSessionSubjectDetail.AASDID, MasterSubject.SubjectName as SubjectName
                FROM         AcdAdmissionSessionSubjectDetail INNER JOIN
                    MasterSubject ON AcdAdmissionSessionSubjectDetail.SubjectId = MasterSubject.SubjectId where
                    AcdAdmissionSessionSubjectDetail.AASDID = @pAASDID
                   ) as ss
          FOR XML PATH(''))  ,1,1,'')




  RETURN @Cols1

      END
  ```

Comment: Ask Sandeep he'll tell you the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
SP_CONFIGURE 'nested_triggers',0
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```